# Fallo al eliminar objeto de lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al ejecutar mi código me sale el fallo de que al intentar eliminar un elemento de una lista, este no se encuentra en ella. Utilizo choices para obtener aleatoriamente varios elementos de una lista y luego, esos mismos elementos eliminarlos. Realmente esto es solo para probar cosas y no creo que lo use en el código final, pero claro, si me está fallando quiero ver por qué es, por si me hiciera falta en el futuro.

Creo que el problema es que choices aleatoriamente coge n elementos de la lista, pero puede repetirse, es decir, me puede coger el mismo elemento 2 o más veces, ¿es eso así? Posteo salida de mi código.

```py
Ghoul Azul
Ghoul Azul
Esqueleto Blanco
Ghoul Azul
Esqueleto Blanco
Goblin Verde
Cofre Morado
Pocima Naranja

Mago Azul
Mago Azul
Guerrero Verde
Guerrero Verde
Guerrero Verde
Mago Azul
Pergamino Marrón

Esqueleto Blanco
Esqueleto Blanco
Esqueleto Blanco

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Documentos/Phyton/Tutoriales/Programas/Dungeon Roll/Batalla.py", line 57, in <module>
    batalla.eliminar_dados(enemigos)
  File "d:/Documentos/Phyton/Tutoriales/Programas/Dungeon Roll/Batalla.py", line 31, in eliminar_dados
    metodo_eliminar(eliminar_enemigo, self.grupo_enemigo)
  File "d:/Documentos/Phyton/Tutoriales/Programas/Dungeon Roll/Batalla.py", line 29, in metodo_eliminar
    grupo.remove(i)
```

También posteo el código:

```py
from random import choices
from Dados import Dados
""" Importa el módulo Dados, que contiene la clase Dados. """

class Batalla:
    """ Proceso de las luchas en dungeon roll. """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Inicializa los grupos enemigos y aliados como listas. """
        self.grupo_aliado = []
        self.grupo_enemigo = []
        self.guarida_dragon = []

    def add(self, tipo, figura = None, cantidad=1):
        """ Añade una cantidad de aliados o enemigos aleatorios o específicos al grupo adecuado. Devuelve True si hay dragones en el grupo enemigo"""
        if tipo == "enemigo":
            dado = self.grupo_enemigo
        if tipo == "aliado":
            dado = self.grupo_aliado
        for i in range(cantidad):
            dado.append(Dados(tipo, figura))
        if "Dragón" in self.grupo_enemigo:
            print("Dragones")

    def eliminar_dados(self, eliminar_enemigo = None, eliminar_aliado = None):
        """ Elimina aliados o enemigos específicos del grupo adecuado. """
        def metodo_eliminar(eliminados, grupo):
            """ Submétodo para eliminar los dados especificados. """
            for i in eliminados:
                grupo.remove(i)
        if eliminar_enemigo is not None:
            metodo_eliminar(eliminar_enemigo, self.grupo_enemigo)
        if eliminar_aliado is not None:
            metodo_eliminar(eliminar_aliado, self.grupo_aliado)

    def guarida_dragon(self):
        pass


batalla = Batalla()
batalla.add("enemigo", cantidad=8)
for i in range(len(batalla.grupo_enemigo)):
    print(batalla.grupo_enemigo[i].figura, batalla.grupo_enemigo[i].color)

print("")

batalla.add("aliado", cantidad=7)
for i in range(len(batalla.grupo_aliado)):
    print(batalla.grupo_aliado[i].figura, batalla.grupo_aliado[i].color)

print("")
enemigos = choices(batalla.grupo_enemigo, k=3)
for i in enemigos:
    print(i.figura, i.color)

print("")

batalla.eliminar_dados(enemigos)
for i in range(len(batalla.grupo_enemigo)):
    print(batalla.grupo_enemigo[i].figura, batalla.grupo_enemigo[i].color)
```

```py
from random import choices
""" Importa choices para generar opciones aleatorios con una probabilidad específica. """

class Dados:
    """ Crea un objeto, enemigo o compañero, con los atributos figura y color. """
    caras_grupo = {
        "Guerrero":"Verde",
        "Templario":"Blanco",
        "Mago":"Azul",
        "Ladrón":"Morado",
        "Pergamino":"Marrón",
        "Campeón":"Amarillo"
    }

    caras_mazmorra = {
        "Goblin":"Verde",
        "Esqueleto":"Blanco",
        "Ghoul":"Azul",
        "Cofre":"Morado",
        "Pocima":"Naranja",
        "Dragón":"Rojo"
    }

    def __init__(self, tipo, figura=None):
        """ Devuelve el par clave:valor de un diccionario. Donde la clave es una figura y el valor un color. """
        if tipo == "enemigo":
            self.caras = dict(Dados.caras_mazmorra)

        if tipo == "aliado":
            self.caras = dict(Dados.caras_grupo)

        if figura is None:
            posibilidades = [i for i in self.caras.keys()]
            eleccion = choices(posibilidades, weights=[2,2,2,2,1,1])
            self.figura, self.color = eleccion[0], self.caras[eleccion[0]]
        else:
            self.figura, self.color = figura, self.caras[figura]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es bastante simple en realidad pero fácil de pasar por alto. La culpa la tiene la línea:

```
enemigos = choices(batalla.grupo_enemigo, k=3)
```

Veamos que dice la documentación sobre `random.choices`:

> Return a `k` sized list of elements chosen from the population **with replacement**. If the population is empty, raises `IndexError`.

traducido libremente:

> Devuelva una lista de elementos de tamaño `k` elegidos de la población **con reemplazo**. Si la población está vacía, lanza una excepción `IndexError`.

Es decir, que `enemigos` puede contener un mismo objeto de `batalla.grupo_enemigo` varias veces, aunque solo esté una vez en `batalla.grupo_enemigo`. Lógicamente cuando intentas eliminarlo repetidamente tienes el error, simplificando tu código para reproducir el problema:

```
from random import choices

enemigos = ["enemigo1", "enemigo2"]
enemigos_a_aliminar = choices(enemigos, k=3)

print("Enemigos: ", enemigos)              
print("A eliminar:", enemigos_a_aliminar)  


for enemigo in enemigos_a_aliminar:
    enemigos.remove(enemigo)
```

> ```
> Enemigos: ['enemigo1', 'enemigo2']
> A eliminar : ['enemigo2', 'enemigo2', 'enemigo2']  # 3 veces 'enemigo2'... XD
> Exception has occurred: ValueError
>     list.remove(x): x not in list
> ```

La solución en principio es simplemente usar [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample) en vez de `random.choices` para esta línea, teniendo en cuenta que `k` no supere `len(batalla.grupo_enemigo)` nunca.

```
from random import sample

enemigos = ["enemigo1", "enemigo2", "enemigo3"]
enemigos_a_aliminar = sample(enemigos, k=2)

print("Enemigos: ", enemigos)              
print("A eliminar:", enemigos_a_aliminar)  


for enemigo in enemigos_a_aliminar:
    enemigos.remove(enemigo)

print("Quedan: ", enemigos)
```

> ```
> Enemigos:  ['enemigo1', 'enemigo2', 'enemigo']
> A eliminar: ['enemigo3', 'enemigo2']
> Quedan:  ['enemigo1']
> ```